# git push from local machine to server works but not files on server

Tags: git

thanks for any help.

I have a git repo on my local machine (mac osx lion) which I'm trying to push to my ec2 instance with Ubuntu.

On the ec2 server I've done:

```
cd /u/apps
mkdir stuff.git
cd stuff.git
git init --bare
git update-server-info
```

On my local machine I've got the folder 'stuff' which just has a text file.

```
cd stuff
git init
git add .
git commit -m "initial commit"
git remote add origin user@111.111.111.111:/u/apps/stuff.git
git push origin master

Counting objects: 6, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 477 bytes, done.
Total 4 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To user@111.111.111.111:/u/apps/stuff.git
95d5ae5..4b5a30f  master -> master
```

everything appears to be fine but when I check the server the new text file called 'hello.txt' hasn't been added. All I see is:

```
/u/apps/stuff.git$ ls
branches  config  description  HEAD  hooks  info  objects  refs
```

Any thoughts on what I may have overlooked?

Cheers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you don't see the files because you created a bare repo ( `git init --bare`) as it should be. Bare repos don't have a working tree.

If you are trying to get the file at a particular path, from the bare repository on thte server, you must setup a post-receive hook and have it checkout. The post receive hook will have something like:

```
GIT_WORK_TREE=/path/where/to/checkout git checkout -f
```

(the above can also be run manually from the repo on the server if you want.)

Comment: Hey manojlds -  I'm trying to do the opposite and push files from my local machine to my server which has the bare repo rather than get a file from the server. thanks anyways.

Comment: @Dandan - Um, that is what I meant.

Comment: sorry bro, I see what you meant. That seems to have done the trick. What I've got so far plus the mentioned extra step, would this be the normal way to go about setting up and pushing files from a local machine to server?